# I question the same as you answer

Tags: riddle

No one can see me, everyone hears me, I converse with you eternally. I speak every language, I make all the new ones, nothing but death surpasses me. I am the mastermind of criminals, as well as the heroes, I know all things anything has discovered. I don't take form, I only exist, and if you ask me, I only give you your best guess. Who or what am I?

Comment: Should that "anything" be "anyone"? Is it a clue?

Comment: As long as it's living.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

> Conscience

Reason:

> Conscience is an internal voice, so everyone hears, but noone sees. As everyone has one, all languages are represented. Death kills the inner voice.

No there yet:

> "I know all things anything has discovered" - not sure about that one.

Comment: Originally, it was "thought", though conscience works just the same. With your answer, conscience, conscience discovers, and thus "knows" what you discover. I may have to make changes in the way I asked my question, well done.